# Do I need @Repository annotation when extending CrudRepository (Spring)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, repository

```
public interface CarRepository extends CrudRepository<Car, Long> {

    Optional<Car> findByCarId(String carId);

    Iterable<Car> findAllByDealerName(String dealerName);
}
```

I have the following repository and my program works just fine.

In a lot of tutorials I see however that even when you extend CrudRepository, you should use the @Repository annotation.

Do I need it or not?

Comment: No, you don't need to add `@Repository` explicitly. Spring Data understands that your interface is a repository interface because it extends `CrudRepository`.

Answer (score 5):

No you don't need the `@Repository` annotation. It is superfluous and does nothing for Spring Data repositories.